# How to get block names of current page?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want get all used block names of current pages kindly reply me

Comment: why do you need all block names ? and from where you need to get it ?

Comment: My custom extension add block name admin

Comment: didn't get you. Add more details to your question

Comment: in my extension user can add product blocks like product.list,search_result_list..after that depends on adding blocks add follow next conditions..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this:

```
$blocks = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getAllBlocks();
```

This will give you an array with the block instances. To get only the names use this:

```
$blockNames = array_keys($blocks);
```

Comment: You are genius... hats off u upvote  to u

Answer (score 3):

Magento,get list `child of a block  using _sortedChildren` variable of this block object

Suppose if want get all child block name of root block then

just`block from layout  and fetch block and get list of child block name`:

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root');

 $childBlockNameCollection=$block ->_sortedChildren;
  echo "<pre>";
 print_r($childBlockNameCollection);
 echo "</pre>";
```

**Do recursive  function get all list of child block.**